# MySQL Query - Convert ResultSet to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I need to convert `select * from {table_name}` into JSON output.Instead of specifying separate key-value pair in 'JSON_OBJECT'.

I have tried this query

```
select JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object("col_name_1",alias.column_1,"col_name_2",alias.column_2)) from {table_name} alias;
```

This one is giving me results what I need, but my question is instead of giving as key-value pair in json_object I need to fetch all columns by giving something like '*'.

MySQL Database Version: `5.7.24`

Comment: In MySQL, you can't. You need to enumerate the key/value pairs.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have tried this query "select JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object("col_name_1",alias.column_1,"col_name_2",alias.column_2))
from {table_name} alias;" This one is giving me result what i need, but my question is instead of giving as key-value pair in json_object i need to fetch all columns by giving something like '*'.

Comment: please edit your question with such details rather than commenting.Btw, what's your DB version ? 8- or 8+ ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Updated the question as per your request.